# Why difference in magnetic field generate electric current? How is induced electric current generated?in simple words please,I'm a average 10th grader

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

Why does moving magnet set charges to motion in a conductor?why?why does difference in magnetic field produce electric current? please can someone answer in simple language and not use many technical terms,terms which a typical 10th grader might not know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a changing magnetic field produce a current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284261/)

Comment: Pay particular attention to the last sentence of ProfRob's answer.

Comment: Thanks,but the thing is I'm not satisfied with the answers,and also the concepts they speak of is not known to me,I'm a average 10th grade student and had this question,if u can explain it in few simple words here I'll be very grateful

Comment: Please edit your question to say specifically what parts of the previous Q&A's you don't understand. But if you really want to know the fundamental reason *why* magnetic fields affect charges, the answer is "we don't know". We just observe that these things happen and write equations to describe what we observe.

Comment: More subtly, we can say that we observe that moving charges have different effect on each other than stationary charges, and we invented the concept of the magnetic field to describe that effect. And that using relativity we can understand that the effects of the magnetic field are just effects of electric field but in a different frame of reference. But then you will still be left asking "but why are those things true?" and so on.

Comment: Hmm,so basically,the answers of my question is not known to anyone, right?and about the previous answers,I didn't understood anything,they were using some formulas and talking about things I have not studied yet,maybe those were beyond 10th grade

Comment: Yeah,you are right I want to know why do they exist?much like asking why does gravity exist(although gravity might have an answer)

Comment: So basically,the answers to these questions don't exist, right?no one knows them,we just know how they work and all,but we don't know why they are even there in the first place or what is causing them, right?

Comment: Basically yes. There are people here who could go deeper down the rabbit hole and tell you about string theory or Noether's theorem, but in the end even they have to start with some observations that we can not explain but only describe, and use those to build their theory of why electric and magnetic fields do what they do.

Comment: Oh,ok,thanks a lot for ur efforts,hope u have a great day and you achieve all your dreams in life